# Multiple RMI Connections from single JVM using Weblogic RMI over T3

Tags: java, weblogic, rmi, jndi

I'm attempting to use JMeter with some custom samplers to load test a Java application that is normally accessed via Weblogic RMI over T3 from a Swing-based GUI. Intention is to load the application server and measure the response time of particular transactions by simulating many concurrent user connections/interactions (up to ~500).

I have implemented a couple of JMeter samplers that acquire a RMI connection to the server via a JNDI lookup and that works fine. However I've noticed that, even if I acquire two contexts on different threads using different credentials, only one T3 connection is opened.

Is there a way to effectively create multiple independent connections to the app server from within one JVM, or will I be forced to run one user per JVM?

App is running in WLS 11g, currently on Hotspot 32bit but will be moving to JRockit 64bit.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are running up against RMI connection pooling. There are ways to turn it down, see the RMI Home Page and the Properties pages linked from them, but it's still an unrealistic test for other reasons such as port exhaustion on the client host. You should really look at using as many client hosts as possible with as many separate JVMs as possible.